# Checking for prime number in boolean expression without defining a function

Tags: oracle, plsql

Could the following PL/SQL code be completed by providing some boolean expression for `IF` statement?

```
declare
   N int := extract(year from sysdate);
begin
   if INSERT_YOUR_BOOLEAN_EXPRESSION_HERE then
      dbms_output.put_line('Current year is prime number.');
   else
      dbms_output.put_line('Current year is not prime number.');
   end if;
end;
```

Obviously, you can't define your own function.
Only standard Oracle 11g PL/SQL functions are allowed.
The code should work properly during years 2014-9999.

---

**EDIT :**
Answer is accepted, but problem is not solved as it was desired.
So, let's go on.

Let's reduce time interval to just 256 years in nearest future: 2014-2269
Will you be able to find another solution, more clever and more compact, without external dependencies outside Oracle server?
It requires some bright idea to succeed in this task.

---

**EDIT #2 :**
The current record is 41 symbols long: `not regexp_like(rpad(1,N,1),'^(11+)\1+$')`
Now may be someone can provide even more brilliant solution?
I would be impressed enough to award one more king-size bounty ))
Beat the current record by at least 1 symbol.

Comment: do you expect community to reproduce the answer you already know or do you expect something new?

Comment: @beherenow - Both cases are good :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Second Attempt - 40 characters**

```
regexp_instr(rpad(2,N+1),'2(  +)\1+$')=0
```

Based on @vav's answer, with a few minor changes.  Replacing `not regexp_like...` with `regexp_count...=0` saves one character.  The other changes are cosmetic - replacing the character 1 with 2 to distinguish between the character and the backreference; using N+1, the default rpad parameter, and spaces just to show a slightly different way to do it.  `regexp_count` could also work here but that function is newer than other regular expression functions.

**First Attempt - 54 characters**

Here is a completely impracticable solution that just so happens to use a very small number of characters for the expression (54), and in no way resembles code golf.

```
declare
   N int := extract(year from sysdate);
begin
   if httpuritype('goo.gl/qMu5eR').getClob like'% '||n||' %' then
      dbms_output.put_line('Current year is prime number.');
   else
      dbms_output.put_line('Current year is not prime number.');
   end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, here is another solution:

```
declare
N int := extract(year from sysdate);
begin
if not regexp_like(rpad('1', N, '1'),'^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$')
then
   dbms_output.put_line('Current year is prime number.');
else
   dbms_output.put_line('Current year is not prime number.');
end if;
end;
```

It is good up to 32767 (size of varchar2 in PL/SQL)

Comment: Brilliant!  If you remove some extra spaces, use implicit conversion for `'1'`, and remove `'1?$|` (restricting the solution a little but still within the relevant years), it's only 42 characters.  I think Egor owes you 550 points now (see his previous question).

Comment: O_o can you give a brief description of your regex?

Comment: Here is a link with some level of explanation: http://montreal.pm.org/tech/neil_kandalgaonkar.shtml

Comment: Wonderful!  This is the solution I was mentioned before.  It is 45 symbols long (non-greedy symbol `?` may be omitted - we don't mind the performance): `not regexp_like(rpad('1',N,'1'),'^(11+)\1+$')`.  BTW, `rpad` limits the year to 4000 only :-(

Comment: I checked with Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 - it is working with year 32767.

Comment: get rid of 'not':  0=regexp_instr(rpad(' ',N),'^(..+)\1+$')

Answer (score 2):

Make it all on one screen and require no internet connection:

```
declare
   N int := extract(year from sysdate);
begin
   if case
   when least(
            mod(N, 2),  mod(N, 3),  mod(N, 5),  mod(N, 7),  mod(N, 11) 
           ,mod(N, 13), mod(N, 17), mod(N, 19), mod(N, 23), mod(N, 29)
           ,mod(N, 31), mod(N, 37), mod(N, 41), mod(N, 43), mod(N, 47)
           ,mod(N, 53), mod(N, 59), mod(N, 61), mod(N, 67), mod(N, 71)
           ,mod(N, 73), mod(N, 79), mod(N, 83), mod(N, 89), mod(N, 97)
           )
 = 0 then 'NOT PRIME'     
ELSE 'PRIME'
end = 'PRIME' then
  dbms_output.put_line('Current year is prime number.');
else
  dbms_output.put_line('Current year is not prime number.');
end if;
end;
```

Comment out last 2 lines of mods if you OK to stay under 2269.
It is scalable to a certain degree, it goes with O(sqrt(n)).

Comment: Correct, but too bulky.  Think more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare
   N int := extract(year from sysdate);
begin
   if case
     when N in
       (2017, 2027, 2029, 2039, 2053, 
        2063, 2069, 2081, 2083, 2087, 2089, 2099, 2111, 2113, 2129, 
        2131, 2137, 2141, 2143, 2153, 2161, 2179, 2203, 2207, 2213, 
        2221, 2237, 2239, 2243, 2251, 2267, 2269, 2273, 2281, 2287, 
        2293, 2297, 2309, 2311, 2333, 2339, 2341, 2347, 2351, 2357, 
        2371, 2377, 2381, 2383, 2389, 2393, 2399, 2411, 2417, 2423, 
        2437, 2441, 2447, 2459, 2467, 2473, 2477, 2503, 2521, 2531, 
        2539, 2543, 2549, 2551, 2557, 2579, 2591, 2593, 2609, 2617, 
        2621, 2633, 2647, 2657, 2659, 2663, 2671, 2677, 2683, 2687, 
        2689, 2693, 2699, 2707, 2711, 2713, 2719, 2729, 2731, 2741, 
        2749, 2753, 2767, 2777, 2789, 2791, 2797, 2801, 2803, 2819, 
        2833, 2837, 2843, 2851, 2857, 2861, 2879, 2887, 2897, 2903, 
        2909, 2917, 2927, 2939, 2953, 2957, 2963, 2969, 2971, 2999, 
        3001, 3011, 3019, 3023, 3037, 3041, 3049, 3061, 3067, 3079, 
        3083, 3089, 3109, 3119, 3121, 3137, 3163, 3167, 3169, 3181, 
        3187, 3191, 3203, 3209, 3217, 3221, 3229, 3251, 3253, 3257, 
        3259, 3271, 3299, 3301, 3307, 3313, 3319, 3323, 3329, 3331, 
        3343, 3347, 3359, 3361, 3371, 3373, 3389, 3391, 3407, 3413, 
        3433, 3449, 3457, 3461, 3463, 3467, 3469, 3491, 3499, 3511, 
        3517, 3527, 3529, 3533, 3539, 3541, 3547, 3557, 3559, 3571, 
        3581, 3583, 3593, 3607, 3613, 3617, 3623, 3631, 3637, 3643, 
        3659, 3671, 3673, 3677, 3691, 3697, 3701, 3709, 3719, 3727, 
        3733, 3739, 3761, 3767, 3769, 3779, 3793, 3797, 3803, 3821, 
        3823, 3833, 3847, 3851, 3853, 3863, 3877, 3881, 3889, 3907, 
        3911, 3917, 3919, 3923, 3929, 3931, 3943, 3947, 3967, 3989, 
        4001, 4003, 4007, 4013, 4019, 4021, 4027, 4049, 4051, 4057, 
        4073, 4079, 4091, 4093, 4099, 4111, 4127, 4129, 4133, 4139, 
        4153, 4157, 4159, 4177, 4201, 4211, 4217, 4219, 4229, 4231, 
        4241, 4243, 4253, 4259, 4261, 4271, 4273, 4283, 4289, 4297, 
        4327, 4337, 4339, 4349, 4357, 4363, 4373, 4391, 4397, 4409, 
        4421, 4423, 4441, 4447, 4451, 4457, 4463, 4481, 4483, 4493, 
        4507, 4513, 4517, 4519, 4523, 4547, 4549, 4561, 4567, 4583, 
        4591, 4597, 4603, 4621, 4637, 4639, 4643, 4649, 4651, 4657, 
        4663, 4673, 4679, 4691, 4703, 4721, 4723, 4729, 4733, 4751, 
        4759, 4783, 4787, 4789, 4793, 4799, 4801, 4813, 4817, 4831, 
        4861, 4871, 4877, 4889, 4903, 4909, 4919, 4931, 4933, 4937, 
        4943, 4951, 4957, 4967, 4969, 4973, 4987, 4993, 4999, 5003, 
        5009, 5011, 5021, 5023, 5039, 5051, 5059, 5077, 5081, 5087, 
        5099, 5101, 5107, 5113, 5119, 5147, 5153, 5167, 5171, 5179, 
        5189, 5197, 5209, 5227, 5231, 5233, 5237, 5261, 5273, 5279, 
        5281, 5297, 5303, 5309, 5323, 5333, 5347, 5351, 5381, 5387, 
        5393, 5399, 5407, 5413, 5417, 5419, 5431, 5437, 5441, 5443, 
        5449, 5471, 5477, 5479, 5483, 5501, 5503, 5507, 5519, 5521, 
        5527, 5531, 5557, 5563, 5569, 5573, 5581, 5591, 5623, 5639, 
        5641, 5647, 5651, 5653, 5657, 5659, 5669, 5683, 5689, 5693, 
        5701, 5711, 5717, 5737, 5741, 5743, 5749, 5779, 5783, 5791, 
        5801, 5807, 5813, 5821, 5827, 5839, 5843, 5849, 5851, 5857, 
        5861, 5867, 5869, 5879, 5881, 5897, 5903, 5923, 5927, 5939,
        5953, 5981, 5987, 6007, 6011, 6029, 6037, 6043, 6047, 6053, 
        6067, 6073, 6079, 6089, 6091, 6101, 6113, 6121, 6131, 6133, 
        6143, 6151, 6163, 6173, 6197, 6199, 6203, 6211, 6217, 6221, 
        6229, 6247, 6257, 6263, 6269, 6271, 6277, 6287, 6299, 6301, 
        6311, 6317, 6323, 6329, 6337, 6343, 6353, 6359, 6361, 6367, 
        6373, 6379, 6389, 6397, 6421, 6427, 6449, 6451, 6469, 6473, 
        6481, 6491, 6521, 6529, 6547, 6551, 6553, 6563, 6569, 6571, 
        6577, 6581, 6599, 6607, 6619, 6637, 6653, 6659, 6661, 6673, 
        6679, 6689, 6691, 6701, 6703, 6709, 6719, 6733, 6737, 6761, 
        6763, 6779, 6781, 6791, 6793, 6803, 6823, 6827, 6829, 6833, 
        6841, 6857, 6863, 6869, 6871, 6883, 6899, 6907, 6911, 6917, 
        6947, 6949, 6959, 6961, 6967, 6971, 6977, 6983, 6991, 6997, 
        7001, 7013, 7019, 7027, 7039, 7043, 7057, 7069, 7079, 7103, 
        7109, 7121, 7127, 7129, 7151, 7159, 7177, 7187, 7193, 7207, 
        7211, 7213, 7219, 7229, 7237, 7243, 7247, 7253, 7283, 7297, 
        7307, 7309, 7321, 7331, 7333, 7349, 7351, 7369, 7393, 7411, 
        7417, 7433, 7451, 7457, 7459, 7477, 7481, 7487, 7489, 7499, 
        7507, 7517, 7523, 7529, 7537, 7541, 7547, 7549, 7559, 7561, 
        7573, 7577, 7583, 7589, 7591, 7603, 7607, 7621, 7639, 7643, 
        7649, 7669, 7673, 7681, 7687, 7691, 7699, 7703, 7717, 7723, 
        7727, 7741, 7753, 7757, 7759, 7789, 7793, 7817, 7823, 7829, 
        7841, 7853, 7867, 7873, 7877, 7879, 7883, 7901, 7907, 7919, 
        7927, 7933, 7937, 7949, 7951, 7963, 7993, 8009, 8011, 8017, 
        8039, 8053, 8059, 8069, 8081, 8087, 8089, 8093, 8101, 8111, 
        8117, 8123, 8147, 8161, 8167, 8171, 8179, 8191, 8209, 8219, 
        8221, 8231, 8233, 8237, 8243, 8263, 8269, 8273, 8287, 8291, 
        8293, 8297, 8311, 8317, 8329, 8353, 8363, 8369, 8377, 8387, 
        8389, 8419, 8423, 8429, 8431, 8443, 8447, 8461, 8467, 8501, 
        8513, 8521, 8527, 8537, 8539, 8543, 8563, 8573, 8581, 8597, 
        8599, 8609, 8623, 8627, 8629, 8641, 8647, 8663, 8669, 8677, 
        8681, 8689, 8693, 8699, 8707, 8713, 8719, 8731, 8737, 8741, 
        8747, 8753, 8761, 8779, 8783, 8803, 8807, 8819, 8821, 8831, 
        8837, 8839, 8849, 8861, 8863, 8867, 8887, 8893, 8923, 8929, 
        8933, 8941, 8951, 8963, 8969, 8971, 8999, 9001, 9007, 9011, 
        9013, 9029, 9041, 9043, 9049, 9059, 9067, 9091, 9103, 9109, 
        9127, 9133, 9137, 9151, 9157, 9161, 9173, 9181, 9187, 9199, 
        9203, 9209, 9221, 9227, 9239, 9241, 9257, 9277, 9281, 9283, 
        9293, 9311, 9319, 9323, 9337, 9341, 9343, 9349, 9371, 9377, 
        9391, 9397, 9403, 9413, 9419, 9421, 9431, 9433, 9437, 9439, 
        9461, 9463, 9467, 9473, 9479, 9491, 9497, 9511, 9521, 9533, 
        9539, 9547, 9551, 9587, 9601, 9613, 9619, 9623, 9629, 9631, 
        9643, 9649, 9661, 9677, 9679, 9689, 9697, 9719, 9721, 9733, 
        9739, 9743, 9749, 9767, 9769, 9781, 9787, 9791, 9803, 9811, 
        9817, 9829, 9833, 9839, 9851, 9857, 9859, 9871, 9883, 9887, 
        9901, 9907, 9923, 9929, 9931, 9941, 9949, 9967, 9973)
     then 'PRIME'
     ELSE 'NOT PRIME'
   end = 'PRIME' then
      dbms_output.put_line('Current year is prime number.');
   else
      dbms_output.put_line('Current year is not prime number.');
   end if;
end;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Solution is correct, but cumbersome and non-scalable   ;-)  Could you give a bit more graceful solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
   N int := extract(year from sysdate);
begin
   if mod(n,2)<>0 and mod(n,3)<>0 and mod(n,5)<>0 and mod(n,7)<>0 
   and mod(n,11)<>0 and mod(n,13)<>0 and mod(n,17)<>0 and mod(n,19)<>0
   and mod(n,23)<>0 and mod(n,29)<>0 and mod(n,31)<>0 and mod(n,37)<>0
   and mod(n,41)<>0 and mod(n,43)<>0 and mod(n,47)<>0 then 
      dbms_output.put_line('Current year is prime number.');
   else
      dbms_output.put_line('Current year is not prime number.');
   end if;
end;
```

This works stable for the interval 2014-2269

UPD: Minimum number of comparisons i've found is:

```
when mod(n,10) in (1,3,7,9) and mod(n,3)<>0
and mod(n,7)<>0 and mod(n,11)<>0 and mod(n,13)<>0
and mod(n,17)<>0 and mod(n,19)<>0 and mod(n,23)<>0
and mod(n,29)<>0 and mod(n,31)<>0 and mod(n,37)<>0
and mod(n,41)<>0 and mod(n,43)<>0 and mod(n,47)<>0
```

Comment: Nice feature with `mod(n,10) in (...)`.  But still too bulky.  Please try to find a way to effectively shrink this long boolean expression to very compact form.